# How to capture full screen by pressing floating button?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, screenshot, floating-action-button

I wanna capture full screen, not widget by pressing floating button with flutter.
It's a mobile app. I tried `screenshot, native_screenshot` packages. In the end, I knew that they are not suitable with my requirement.
Now I am trying with `RenderRepaintBoundary`.

`RenderRepaintBoundary boundary = GlobalKey().currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderRepaintBoundary;`

Where the `currentContext` is null and exception occured.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach and update with your widget

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyAppScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final GlobalKey boundaryKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Capture Screen'),
      ),
      body: RepaintBoundary(
        key: boundaryKey,
        child: Builder(
          builder: (context) {
            RenderRepaintBoundary? boundary =
                boundaryKey.currentContext?.findRenderObject() as RenderRepaintBoundary?;
            if (boundary != null) {
              // Capture the full screen here
              // You can use the boundary object to capture the image
              captureScreen(boundary);
            }
            return YourScreenWidget();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void captureScreen(RenderRepaintBoundary boundary) {
    // Perform the screen capture and handle the image as needed
    // Example: Save the image to storage or display it in a dialog
    // Here, we just print the image size for demonstration purposes
    final image = boundary.toImage();
    final byteData = image.toByteData(format: ImageByteFormat.png);
    if (byteData != null) {
      print('Captured image size: ${byteData.lengthInBytes} bytes');
    }
  }
}

class YourScreenWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      // Your screen widget content here
      child: Text('Your Screen Content'),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyAppScreen()));
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply. And I wanna using Floating button. It means Overlay Button. Please let me know another ways if you know

Comment: I don't understand this please clarify